# Delphi, кривая прорисовка иконок в Shelllistview после увеличения высоты строк

Tags: delphi, listview

Штатными компонентами пытаюсь увеличить межстрочный интервал между итемами в Shelllistview. Вид отображения иконок использую vsList. Единственный способ, который мне удалось найти, это увеличить высоту строк. Для этого добавляем на форму любой ImageList и выбираем его в StateImages. После чего в ImageList можно задать нужную высоту и строки раздвигаются.

Но при перерисовке иконок, например, если провести над ними мышкой, или открыть папку, появляются артефакты. Не один из найденных в интернете вариантов не помог исправить проблему.

Может кто-нибудь знает, хотя бы примерно, как это победить?

[image: Результат]
[image: Увеличенно]

Comment: Какие артефакты? Я не вижу.

Comment: Под каждой иконкой, например папкой, черная полоска высотой в 2 пикселя. а должен быть белый фон. Это наложение от другой иконки в межстрочном интервале.

Comment: Господи, кто на это смотреть будет? Я даже сразу не заметил. Если это вас так уж сильно беспокоит, обратитесь в службу поддержки Delphi. Боюсь, других вариантов нет. А вообще проверьте, точно это артефакт? Разве наложение прозрачного на прозрачное не дает прозрачного?

Comment: Это расстояние увеличено всего на 2 пикселя, если его увеличить еще больше, то поле становится почти черным, все сливается. Если бы я хоте обратиться в поддержку Delphi, то сюда бы не писал. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот тут обсуждают это дело немного - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569779/change-listview-item-height

Comment: Насколько я помню, там все ImageList'ы должны быть одного разрешения. Вы StateImages добавили, а стандартные иконки как теперь рисовать, они же старого размера остались? Вот и получаются артефакты. Вряд ли эту проблему удастся решить простым способом.